# Scala : cannot check match for unreachibility even with default value

Tags: scala

I'm working on a compiler for a simple language for a course and I ran into this warning. The pattern matching in question is simple so I don't get why this pops up. Here's the pattern matching in question :

```
(tcExpr(lhs), tcExpr(rhs)) match {
      case (TInt, TInt) | (TString, TString) | (TBoolean, TBoolean) | (TIntArray, TIntArray) | (TObject(_), TObject(_)) => TBoolean
      case _ => TError
```

with tcExpr signature being `def tcExpr(expr: ExprTree, expected: Type*): Type`, `ExprTree` representing an expression and the `Type` being case objects. All except `TObject()` are simple objects, and `TObject()` takes a symbol representing a class as argument.

What I don't get is that there are not that many possibilities. Why can't the compiler figure it out ? Is there something I have overlooked, or misunderstood ?

Thank you very much for your answers,

Nicolas

Comment: What's the message the compiler shows you. Can put up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce "warning: Cannot check match for unreachability." with the following code (I don't know how many types you have. I took 32 + 1 as upper bound):

```
trait Type 

case object T0 extends Type
case object T1 extends Type
case object T2 extends Type
case object T3 extends Type
case object T4 extends Type
...
<generated code, 32 types in total>
...
case object T31 extends Type

def foo: Type = T0

(foo, foo) match {
  case (T0,T0) | <total 32 types> | (T31,T31) => println("true")
  case _ => println("false")
}
```

The reason seems to be that it simply runs out of memory trying to check all the possible cases. The advice given by the warning is to add the option `-Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=off` when running the compiler. Just tried to compile with this option: it works, no more warnings.

**EDIT**: Just found out by bisection that without the option, it stops working with >= 5 types... This is not much memory indeed.

My proposal would be to just remove the eternally long enumeration, and replace it by a short and concise equation:

```
(foo, foo) match {
  case (Obj(_), Obj(_)) => println("true")
  case (x, y) if (x == y) => println("true") // Order is important, thx @Nico
  case _ => println("false")
}
```

Then the warning disappears, and the code stops spilling over the 80 characters / line limit.

Comment: I have only 5 types, that's why I don't get the mistake. But your solution is better and cleaner so I'm gonna use it anyway, thanks ! Just wondering, shouldn't the first and second case be reversed ? Otherwise, wouldn't (x, y) catch any tuple ?

Comment: @Nico Indeed, the first and second cases should be swapped. I edited my post. But as I said, in principle you could leave your code as it is, the compiler option eliminates the problem.

Comment: I can not explain why the limit is so low. It seems that it simply refuses to work with > 20 cases or so (5x5 = 25 > 20). Maybe they just tried to avoid exponentially large compile times this way... If it's a single pattern-match in a linearly organized program, many cases do not hurt that much, but it could be different in larger code bases, where it could lead to compilation that takes half a week each time...